# DateTimeFormatter can not parse date with decimal 0 after second in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format

I am using Java 8. I am trying to parse a date to string with DateTimeFormatter. But it gives the following error. My attempt and error are given below.

My code:

```
String getFormatedDateForList(String dateObj) {
    // dateObj = "2019-02-06 00:00:00.0"
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String output = LocalDate.parse(dateObj, inputFormat).format(outputFormat)
    return output
}
```

Error:

`Text '2019-02-06 00:00:00.0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19. Stacktrace follows: Message: Text '2019-02-06 00:00:00.0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19`

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input formatting pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` specifies the first 19 characters, while your input `dateObj` contains more than that. Hence the parser finds unparsed text from the 20th character (index 19) onwards.

Given you have a tenth of a second in `dateObj`, you need to specify that in your formatting pattern. Based on the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), I think you want:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

Comment: What happens if we have an unspecified number of decimals, or none at all? will this pattern still work?

Comment: Generally speaking, the parsers are expecting the text to match the format. If it doesn't you will get an exception.